How to add question in a sharepoint without those questions being added to a power apps galery?
I'm not familiar with PowerApps and I inherited of a "Frequently asked questions" PowerApps in which there's a list of question that are compiled in Sharepoint and then shown through a gallery in PowerApps. There's another page in the PowerApps through which customers can ask question. However, some questions are personal, so they shouldn't add themselves to the gallery even if they are added to the sharepoint file. Now, in the Data section of the Advanced panel on the right, I see a code in Items :
Search(FAQ_PAC;
SearchTextInput.Text;Question;Answer)
I believe the problem is there, but i don't know what. What is the solution ?

I should add that some questions asked are welcome to be added to the gallery if the client said yes on a choice question with a dropdown menu in the PowerApps question page. This information is also present on Sharepoint.

You will need to Filter first based on the column in SharePoint that has the "Yes" column. Try something similar to:
Search(
  Filter(FAQ_PAC; YourYesColumn.Value = "Yes");
  SearchTextInput.Text; Question; Answer
)

See Filter, Search, and LookUp functions for more info.
